# angular material date picker and input

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I format the date that is input in angular material and do not allow users to enter any thing else other than numbers and '/'. After the user enters the date, I should be able to format it for example. MM/DD/YYYY. I was expecting something out of the box to have this functionality without having to install additional components.

Comment: You want to be able to use both the text field and the datepicker modal as well?

Comment: Yes. I want the user to have the liberty.